# Why does my iPhone not show all the backup to restore?

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I forgot to backup a chat history of my messaging app before reinstalling it, so tried to restore my iPhone with a yesterday's backup, but after erasing all the data and going into restore option, I found that the most recent backup was from just a few minutes before (the one with all the messages are gone), and the next backup is the one on January 31rd. I want to restore it with the yesterday's backup, but for some reasons I cannot see it on the list of my backups, nor I cannot see any backup between now and January 31rd.

This makes all of my messages between today and January 31rd gone, so I would rather want to restore it with yesterday's (or even better, today's, though I think iPhone didn't backup today yet).

How can I get the yesterday's backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restore a backup that does not appear on the list.

Apple does not publish the strategy they use to pick which backups are available, but the only guarantee is that the most recent one is available.

Any previous backups that do appear should be considered complimentary, as they don't count towards your storage quota.

Comment: In effect, it's not at all like Time Machine. It doesn't store incremental versions as a matter of course, from which you can pick & choose. Your usual availability is simply "last backup".